# Как получить уровень шума из Wifi карты?

Tags: linux, c, wifi, radio

Карточка отдает уровень сигнала на каждый принятый фрейм - это легко снимается tcpdump-ом. А как получить уровень шума в канале?

Искал интерфейс на C, но пока не нашел.

OpenWrt показывает уровень шума, также есть в RouterOS и AirOS.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: не то? https://superuser.com/questions/1313870/wifi-noise-measurement

Comment: @Hellseher, не то.. тут замер идет относительно STA. В глухом эфире как бы получить...

Comment: гм... а это вообще возможно? Как минимум нужна поддержка со стороны железа... а во-вторых со стороны дров и общий интерфейс со стороны ядра... я, если честно ничего подобного не видел ни на одном из уровней... хотя мои знания, вполне вероятно неполны...

Comment: @Fat-Zer "airview" в airos и "freq. usage" в микротиках есть к примеру)